# Whats wrong with this java method ? I'm getting errors on the start

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm getting errors

Invalid method declaration, return type required
Missing method body

```
private void AutomaticServerConnect()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            response = Get(HttpCommandToSend(iptouse, 8098, "nothing"));
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            if (response != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    final String a = new String(response, "UTF-8");
                    text.post(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            text.setText(a + " On \n" + ipaddresses[counter]);
                            status1.setText("Connected");
                            String successconnected = null;
                            successconnected = "Successfully connected";
                            textforthespeacch = successconnected;
                            MainActivity.this.initTTS();
                        }
                    });
                    iptouse = ipaddresses[i].substring(0, ipaddresses[i].lastIndexOf("=") + 1);
                    connectedtoipsuccess = true;
                    connectedSuccess = true;
                    Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info(a);
                    if (!iptouse.isEmpty())
                    {

                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("encoding exception");
                }    

                Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("test1");
            }
            else
            {
                text.post(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        text.setText("Connection Failed");
                        status1.setText("Connection Failed");
                        String successconnected = null;
                        successconnected = "connection failed";
                        textforthespeacch = successconnected;
                        MainActivity.this.initTTS();
                    }
                });
            }                
        }).start();
    });
```

I'm getting error on the line:

```
}).start();
```

> Invalid method declaration, return type required
>   Missing method body

And also an error on the line

```
});
```

> } expected

Comment: Due to the volatility of all the curly braces involved, if someone sees an indentation oversight in my edit, by all means, please fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Proper indentation will help you find the invalid braces :

```
private void AutomaticServerConnect()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ...
        }).start();
});
```

you closed the `run` method, but not the anonymous `Runnable` instance.

It should be :

```
private void AutomaticServerConnect()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ...
        } // added }
    }).start();
} // removed );
```

Answer (score -1):

Count your curly braces.  You are missing a close brace somewhere.